# How to pass a container as a parameter and not change its value java?

Tags: java

[This programmers stack exchange question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286008/parameters-are-passed-by-value-but-editing-them-will-edit-the-actual-object-li) enlightened me to the java programming concept container objects are passed in as pointers. Upon learning that, I have an issue with my code because of that concept.

Here is my code:

```
public double findRollingPivots(ArrayList<Double> listOfCurrentPivots, ArrayDeque<Double> dequeOfAllPivots, double rollingPeriodLength) {
   double returnSignal = 0; //this is whatever signal to be returned-- BD BO or profit target
   double containerOfPivots = 0; //this holds all of the pivots to be divided in dequeOfCurrentPivots
   listOfCurrentPivots.remove(4); /***line4***/
   listOfCurrentPivots.add(dequeOfAllPivots.removeLast());

   for (int i = 0; i < rollingPeriodLength; i++) { /***line 6***/
       containerOfPivots += listOfCurrentPivots.get(i);
   }

   returnSignal = containerOfPivots / rollingPeriodLength;

   return returnSignal;
```

My issue is that on line 4, I will not always be removing the element at the fourth index. It would be much easier to just call `removeLast()` on a `deque` and just `push` the new element on each time.

But, if I use a `deque`, then on line 6, I will be losing all of my elements when I add them to the `containerOfPivots` variable. I tried to get around this by creating a temporary `deque` to use so I can keep the parameter value, but that doesn't work either. So, is there a way to use a `deque` and not have to worry about depleting the size of it in a function? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Why not to use iterator?

Comment: I was unaware of iterator; I am new to java. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: This is the main purpose of the list. If it doesn't have next/previous pointer access directly, it needs iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (you'd like to avoid modifying the original list within your function), you can make a copy of the collection with all the same elements.

```
List<Double> newList = new ArrayList<Double>();
newList.addAll(listOfCurrentPivots);
```

Any changes made to *newList* will have no effect on the elements contained in *listOfCurrentPivots*. This will not duplicate the amount of data we are dealing with either. Each list will reference the same object in memory. Since we are dealing with Doubles they are immutable so we don't have to worry about operations that would modify these objects.

Comment: I'm going to try that. thank you I was unaware that this was a method.